# Datatables Filtering rows by row icons class

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, datatables

I am using a backbone collection `this.courseTemplates` to populate my table. One of my columns is populated by icons that have a class depending on their schedule status. This status is found by using a function `checkScheduleStatus` which returns either `"All"`, `"Part"` or `"Unscheduled"`. And they give the icon tags these classes respectively `cpTableAllScheduledIcon`, `cpTablePartScheduledIcon` &  `cpTableUnScheduledIcon` I want to be able to filter rows by their schedule status returned from `checkScheduleStatus`

So, say I have a checkbox and I select `"All"` & `"Part"` I don't want to view any that are "`unscheduled`". Is this possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Below is my datatables code

```
render: function() {
    var self = this;

    this.ui.courseTemplateTbody.empty();

    this.courseTable = $('#courseTplTable').DataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bStateSave": true,
        "deferRender": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
            [5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
        ],
        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "order": [
            [0, '']
        ],
        "columnDefs": [{
            "orderable": false,
            "targets": [0, 5]
        }, ],
        "aaData": self.courseTemplates.toJSON(),
        "aoColumns": [{
            "sTitle": "",
            "orderable": false,
            "mDataProp": function(row) {
                var status = self.checkScheduleStatus(row);
                if (status === "All") {
                    return '<i id="ctScheduleStatus" class="cpTableAllScheduledIcon octicon octicon-check protip" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-title="Course Template Scheduled" data-pt-position="right" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-size="small"></i>';
                } else if (status === "Part") {
                    return '<i id="ctScheduleStatus" class="cpTablePartScheduledIcon fa fa-exclamation protip" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '"  data-pt-title="Course Template Part-Scheduled" data-pt-position="right" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-size="small"></i>';
                } else {
                    return '<i id="ctScheduleStatus" class="cpTableUnScheduledIcon octicon octicon-x protip" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-title="Course Template Unscheduled" data-pt-position="right" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-size="small"></i>';
                }
            }
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Course",
            "mDataProp": function(row) {
                return '<div class="cpTableCourseNameWrap">' +
                    '<div class="cpTableCourseName">' + self.getCourseTitle(row['CourseString']) + '</div>' +
                    '<div class="cpTableCourseDuration">' + self.getCourseDuration(row['CourseString']) + '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
            }

        }, {
            "sTitle": "Demand",
            "mDataProp": function(row) {
                return '<div class="cpTableCourseDemandWrap">' +
                    '<div class="hidden">' + row['NumRequired'] + '</div>' +
                    '<button data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" class="cpTableCourseDemandBtn cpDemandDecrease" style="margin-right: 5px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;">' +
                    '<i class="octicon octicon-dash"></i>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<input data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" class="cpDemandInput" type="text" value="' + row['NumRequired'] + '" />' +
                    '<button data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" class="cpTableCourseDemandBtn cpDemandIncrease" style="margin-left: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;">' +
                    '<i class="octicon octicon-plus"></i>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '</div>';
            }

        }, {
            "sTitle": "Courses",
            "mDataProp": function(row) {
                return '<div id="courseCount" class="cpTableCourseCountWrap" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '">' + row['ModuleIndexList'].length + '</div>';
            }
        }, {
            "sTitle": "Status",
            "mDataProp": function(row) {
                return '<div>' +
                    '<div class="cpTableStatusGreen protip" data-pt-title="Courses Scheduled" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-position="top" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-size="small"><i class="octicon octicon-check"></i><span>' + self.getScheduleTotals(row['ModuleIndexList'])[0] + '</span></div>' +
                    '<div class="cpTableStatusYellow protip" data-pt-title="Courses Part Scheduled" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-position="top" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-size="small"><i class="fa fa-exclamation"></i><span>' + self.getScheduleTotals(row['ModuleIndexList'])[1] + '</span></div>' +
                    '<div class="cpTableStatusRed protip" data-pt-title="Courses Unscheduled" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-position="top" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-size="small"><i class="octicon octicon-x"></i><span>' + self.getScheduleTotals(row['ModuleIndexList'])[2] + '</span></div>' +
                    '</div>';
            }
        }, {
            "sTitle": "",
            "orderable": false,
            "searchable": false,
            "mDataProp": function(row) {
                return '<div class="cpTableCourseOptionsWrap">' +
                    '<div class="btn-group" role="group">' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary protip cpViewCoursesBtn" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-title="View Courses" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-position="top" data-pt-size="small"><i class="octicon octicon-eye"></i><span>View Courses</span></button>' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-info protip cpEditTplBtn" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-title="Edit Template" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-position="top" data-pt-size="small"><i class="octicon octicon-pencil"></i><span>Edit Template</span></button>' +
                    '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger protip cpDeleteTplBtn" data-id="' + row['OptimeIndex'] + '" data-pt-title="Delete Template" data-pt-scheme="black" data-pt-position="top" data-pt-size="small"><i class="octicon octicon-trashcan"></i><span>Delete Template</span></button>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
            }
        }]
    });

},
```

I'll throw in my `checkScheduleStatus` function in case it is any use

```
checkScheduleStatus: function(courseTpl) {
    var self = this;

    var status = "";

    var scheduleCount = 0;
    var unscheduledCount = 0;
    var partScheduledCount = 0;

    //Go through each course (module) and check each of its events and get its scheduled status
    _.each(courseTpl['ModuleIndexList'], function(moduleId) {
        var module = self.modules.get(moduleId);

        if (module !== undefined && module !== null) {

            _.each(module.get('EventIds'), function(eventId) {
                var event = self.events.get(eventId);
                var roomAlloc = self.events.get(eventId).get('Rooms');
                var staffAlloc = self.events.get(eventId).get('StaffAllocations');
                var weeks = self.events.get(eventId).get('Weeks');
                var period = self.events.get(eventId).get('Period');

                if (roomAlloc.length > 0 && staffAlloc.length > 0) {
                    scheduleCount++;
                }
                if (roomAlloc.length > 0 && staffAlloc.length === 0) {
                    partScheduledCount++;
                }
                if (roomAlloc.length === 0 && staffAlloc.length > 0) {
                    partScheduledCount++;
                }
                if (roomAlloc.length === 0 && staffAlloc.length === 0 && weeks !== undefined && period !== undefined) {
                    partScheduledCount++;
                }
                if (roomAlloc.length === 0 && staffAlloc.length === 0 && weeks !== undefined && period === undefined) {
                    unscheduledCount++;
                }
                if (roomAlloc.length === 0 && staffAlloc.length === 0 && weeks === undefined) {
                    unscheduledCount++;
                }
            });
        }
    });

    if (scheduleCount === 0 && partScheduledCount === 0)
        status = "Unscheduled";
    else if (partScheduledCount > 0)
        status = "Part";
    else if (scheduleCount > 0 && unscheduledCount > 0)
        status = "Part";
    else if (unscheduledCount === 0 && partScheduledCount === 0)
        status = "All";

    return status;
},
```